# How to write text on image in objective-c iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, uiimageview

I want to write some text on an image and save it as png with reduced size. is it possible in objective-c iPhone?

Tell me the best possible answer. or any sample code for it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: search engines are your friend (we would expect you to try something first, then ask for help when it didn't work).  SO is not a `give me teh codez` site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Follow this... [how to draw on Image](http://sites.google.com/site/iprogramiphones/bukisatutorials/drawingoveranimage) and download sample code from there and see how it will works...